# Using AWS DynamoDB to save session information in Grails 3

Tags: tomcat, grails, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-dynamodb

As I want to be able to persist http sessions across multiple instances of my Grails 3 application (running in Elastic Beanstalk) I am looking to use DynamoDb as mentioned [HERE](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/java-dg-tomcat-session-manager.html)

(Basically one provides in WEB-INF, a special dynamodb jar, a context file and a .config file which contains instructions for aws to copy these 2 files into the local tomcat instance on aws)

After lots of issues with aws security keys etc I finally got my grails app to successfully deploy and start up on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk. However when I save something to the session I dont see anything in the DyanmoDb panel of AWS. After looking in the logs I see the following:

connection cleanup thread - but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:

```
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
  com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:43)
28-Jan-2016 20:47:54.595 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2]     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The     web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [java-sdk-    http-connection-reaper] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to     create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
 com.amazonaws.tomcatsessionmanager.amazonaws.http.IdleConnectionReaper.run(IdleConnectionReaper.java:112)
28-Jan-2016 20:47:54.596 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [dynamo-session-manager-expired-sesion-reaper] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)**
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
28-Jan-2016 20:47:54.597 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2]     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [ROOT] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [
```

Wondered if anyone had any ideas how I can resolve this. I'm hoping that once I have dynamodb backing the httpsession that I can spin up as many instances of my web app as possible and still have user sessions work across different servers without relying on 'sticky' sessions etc.

Comment: I don't think your log extract is related to your problem. You should show us more logs, config, script, etc.

Comment: you seen this part right:    28-Jan-2016 20:47:54.596 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [dynamo-session-manager-expired-sesion-reaper] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:

Comment: A memory leak doesn't explain why nothing is written in DynamoDB. A memory leak would consume all memory and crash your app after a while.